# vector.dev vrl - add todays date and timezone to parsed time

Tags: vector-vrl

i have a string parsed time, i would like to convert it to timestamp by using todays date + local timezone

for example:

```
.parsed_time = "13:41:41.772863"
```

i tried using parse_timestamp like this:

```
date = format_timestamp!(now(),"%Y-%m-%d")
parsed_time = string!(.parsed_time)
with_date = "{{ date }}T{{ parsed_time }}"
.timestamp = parse_timestamp!(with_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

the problem here is that `now()` is UTC timezone...
any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `parse_timestamp` function will always use **the local time zone** of the machine running Vector.
that could be a real problem when comparing expected values in tests.

to mitigate that issue we can use the TZ env var before running the tests:

```
TZ="Europe/London" vector test *.toml
```

there might be also a global timezone variable we can set before the test start but i still didnt figure out if its really posible.
(see docs here: https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/global-options/#timezone)

my my uptodate code:

```
  date = format_timestamp!(now(),"%Y-%m-%d")
  parsed_time = string!(.parsed_time)
  with_date = "{{ date }}T{{ parsed_time }}"
  .timestamp = parse_timestamp!(with_date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6f")
```

and unit test for this input `.parsed_time = "13:41:41.772863"`:

```
date = format_timestamp!(now(),"%Y-%m-%d")

# We run out tests in GMT+1 (see Makefile) - so we need to adjust the expected time to UTC (1 hour back)
expected_timestamp = "{{ date }}T12:41:41.772863"

assert!(is_timestamp(.timestamp)) # <-- This is the calculated timestamp by todays date + event time in UTC time
timestamp_str = format_timestamp!(.timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6f")
assert_eq!(timestamp_str, expected_timestamp)
```